# Grouped differences in timestampls in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, timestamp

I have a table that looks like the following:

| Transaction ID | Timestamp | User ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-02 8:08 | USER1 |
| 2 | 2021-11-02 8:10 | USER2 |
| 3 | 2021-11-02 8:07 | USER2 |
| 4 | 2021-11-02 8:15 | USER1 |
| 5 | 2021-11-02 8:18 | USER2 |

I want to create a third column, that essentially says, for a given transaction, how long since *that users* last transaction. Essentially, subtract the users last timestamp. The output table would look like this:

| Transaction ID | Timestamp | User ID | Time Taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-02 8:08 | USER1 | None |
| 2 | 2021-11-02 8:10 | USER2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2021-11-02 8:07 | USER2 | None |
| 4 | 2021-11-02 8:15 | USER1 | 7 |
| 5 | 2021-11-02 8:18 | USER2 | 8 |

How can I do this with a query in SQlite3?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `LAG()` along with the `JULIANDAY()` function here:

```sql
SELECT
    TransactionID,
    Timestamp,
    UserID,
    COALESCE(CAST((JULIANDAY(Timestamp) -
                   JULIANDAY(LAG(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID
                       ORDER BY Timestamp))) * 1440 AS INTEGER), 'None') AS "TimeTaken"
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Timestamp;
```

Note that in order for the above to work, your text timestamps will have to be in a valid literal format.  So instead of:

```
2021-11-02 8:08
```

you would need:

```
2021-11-02 08:08:00
```

Comment: All the time taken values are None

Comment: The problem is with the format of your text timestamps.  Once you fix that, the query should work.

Comment: how do I add 00 for all the seconds?

Comment: It might be more than that.  You need ISO timestamp format.  I suggest fixing your data at its source.

Comment: My data sourse is an excel file, how would I get them into ISO?

Comment: Do you have access to a text editor with regex capability?

Comment: Yes. Also, I have just changed the timestamps to have seconds (I realize they have seconds in the original file for some reason they weren't there), so now they're in the format with seconds. Still getting null values for time_taken

Comment: Create a demo at dbfiddle.uk , add your data and my query, and then see what the problem is... sse here: https://dbfiddle.uk/wAGboLLr